# virtuozzo openvz centos 7 container network not start after update

Tags: centos, networking, openvz

After yum upgrade in may 2019 now i have following:

network in container not start.

nothing in log

ps ax show, that  network start script running forever

```
/bin/bash /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth ifcfg-lo
```

After investigating(adding additional debug echo commands) i can see that this line in script never ends

```
ip link set dev venet0 up
```

Any ideas what i have check after that?

Comment: Which version of OpenVZ are you using?  What is the kernel version?  The output of `uname -a` may help.  There was a recent OpenVZ bug (May 2018, [OVZ-7021](https://bugs.openvz.org/browse/OVZ-7021)) that the kernel needed an update to handle the newer versions of the `iproute` tools delivered in CentOS 7.5.  This specific issue should be fixed in the current kernel.

Comment: 3.10.0-693.17.1.vz7.45.8. I have no way restore networking in main os, so i not updating it.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary solution:

copy /sbin/ip from other(older) host.

But i still interesting if anyone know other solution.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/250084)

Comment: Thomas this one is compleate answer, no?

Comment: I do prefer this workaround instead of upgrading the host node as this might not be without risks.